# Java test with Mock Controller

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, mockito, mock

У меня вопрос связанный с тестированием моего контроллера используя mock. В общем я создал проект используя MVC.

У меня есть класс Student у которого методы: setId, setName, setSubjects, getId, getName и getSubjects а также метод toString().

Вот мой View:

```
public class View {
private Student student;
private DiplomaStudent diplomaStudent;

public View() {
    this.student = new Student();
    this.diplomaStudent = new DiplomaStudent();
}

public void inoutStudent() {
    System.out.println("Enter id: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer id = input.nextInt();
    student.setId(id);

    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    Scanner inputName = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = inputName.nextLine();
    student.setStudentName(name);

    System.out.println("Enter course");
    Scanner inputCourse = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer course = inputCourse.nextInt();
    student.setCourse(course);

    System.out.println(student.getId() + " " + student.getStudentName() + " " + student.getCourse());
}

public String inputing() {
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    Scanner inputName = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = inputName.nextLine();

    return name;
}
}
```

Вот мой Controller:

```
public class Controller {
private Student student;
private DiplomaStudent diplomaStudent;
private View view;

public Controller() {
    this.student = new Student();
    this.diplomaStudent = new DiplomaStudent();
    this.view = new View();
}

public void startStud() {
    view.inoutStudent();
}

public String inpt() {
    return view.inputing();
}
}
```

Проблема заключается в том что я пытаюсь протестировать Controller. Но я не знаю как это сдлеать, так как у меня ввод с клавиатуры. Я пытался протестировать View, но моя задача именно Controller протестировать и без тех классов которые я использовал в методе testView(). Подскажите как мне это сделать?

Вот тестирование класса view:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("test immitation from console input")
public void testView(){
    View view = new View();
    String inputName = "Jhon";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputName.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    assertEquals("Jhon", view.inputing());
}

@Test
public void testController() {
    Controller controller = mock(Controller.class);
    //what i should write here
    assertEquals("Jhon", controller.startStud());
    assertEquals("Jhon", controller.inpt());
}
```

Comment: Вы не знаете как подсунуть мок объект или что? Я не понял про что вопрос

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если запустить контроллер с методом startStud() или inpt() то у меня ввод с клавиатуры. Я не знаю как протестировать результаты в testController'e. Я делал то же самое что и с testView(), но ошибки, хотя в самом testView() все нормально и тест срабатывает хорошо.

Comment: Замокать System.in вряд ли что-то даёт

Comment: Сделайте рефакторинг кода - значения, которые вводятся в System.in должны поступать в методы контроллера извне, а не изнутри. Если изнутри, то это нетестируемый черный ящик.

Comment: @RomanC а чем будет плох стрим в котором лежит тестовый ввод?

Comment: @Strangerintheq В стриме никогда ничего не лежит, а может только туда писать или читать, надеюсь что стрим тестировать не нужно?

Comment: @RomanC я имел в виду вот это http://tpcg.io/yKWiiq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте конструктор

```
public Controller(Student student, DiplomaStudent diplomaStudent, View view) {
    this.student = student;
    this.diplomaStudent = diplomaStudent;
    this.view = view;
}
```

А затем "мокайте" входящие аргументы и тестируйте на здоровье

Для упрощения "мокирования" можете использовать библиотеку типа Mockito. В противном случае создайте классы унаследованные от этих типов и переопределите методы так чтобы вы могли проверить, что эти методы вызываются.

Comment: Лучше используйте интерфейсы а не классы, без всякого переопределения вы просто имплиментируете ваш интерфейс.